# Suggested tag synonym: lotus-domino/domino

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

The tags [domino](/questions/tagged/domino) and [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino) seem to be synonyms. I suppose [domino](/questions/tagged/domino) (149 questions) should be the synonym of [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino) (248 questions) since the latter has more questions.

Tag wiki of [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino):

> Lotus Domino is an IBM server product that provides enterprise-grade e-mail, collaboration capabilities, and a custom application platform.

Tag wiki of [domino](/questions/tagged/domino):

> Domino is the server component of IBM Lotus Software Messaging and Collaboration offerings. A typical Domino server supports a variety of applications and protocols that clients can use to access those applications. Applications out-of-the-box include E Mail, Calendaring and other Personal Information Management, Discussions, Teamrooms and many others. Protocols supported are include HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, as well as the RPC protocol for Notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged [domino](/questions/tagged/domino) into [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino).  Additionally, I moved the tag wiki of [domino](/questions/tagged/domino) to [lotus-domino](/questions/tagged/lotus-domino).